# How to sort a column with numeric values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In one of my table column I have values like:

```
"fol v1.1.2",
"fol v1.2.10",
"fol v1.5.6",
"all fols",
"fol v1.7.10 updated 22.03.2019",
"fol v1.10.11"
```

After ordering i need the values like:

```
"all fols",
"fol v1.1.2",
"fol v1.2.10",
"fol v1.5.6",
"fol v1.7.10 updated 22.03.2019",
"fol v1.10.11"
```

Comment: You would need a pretty ugly query to swing this.  For best results, I recommend storing the major and minor versions in separate _number_ columns.  This would make it very easy to sort the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from trial order by substring_index(dat,'.',1),cast(substring_index(substring_index(dat,'.',2),'.',-1) as signed),cast(substring_index(substring_index(dat,'.',3),'.',-1) as signed);
```

what i did is, split the versions in by '.' as a delimiter and then convert into integers then group them according to values.

for more information about splitting refer this [w3resource-mysql-substring](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)